# The Theoretical Physic proposal is back underway!

Tags: discussion

*In reference to: [Disposition of Area 51 Proposal: Theoretical Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/788/disposition-of-area-51-proposal-theoretical-physics)*

**The proposal for creating a "[Theoretical Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics)" site will *not* be closed.**

Thank you to the Physics SE community — You made a persuasive argument for *keeping* the Theoretical Physics proposal alive and on course.

I found your arguments both convincing *and* refreshingly civil. It is my sincere hope that the dual Physics/Theoretical Physics community will become greater than the sum of its parts.

Comment: Well, it was actually the TP.SE community - most of the people I saw arguing to preserve the TP proposal are committed to it but are not (very) active on physics.SE. But I digress.

Comment: Many thanks to you! Let's just hope the dream will come true :) @David: actually, I don't think that's the case. Both me and Qmechanic are quite active here (I'd like to think) while Joe used to be in the past. And I believe many other people here expressed their (silent) support by voting. Anyway, let's not overanalyse it and just hope that both sites will be great :)

Comment: @Marek: well, you two would be the exceptions ;-) As I recall, Joe and others bailed on the physics site almost immediately after it was formed... but anyway, that doesn't matter. Personally I still think that if TP.SE launches, it kills any chance that physics.SE will someday become successful, but of course I can't predict the future. Let's hope that I'm wrong, indeed.

Comment: Where will experimental physicists fit in this proposed future? Do they need to create their own SE proposal?

Comment: @lurscher: well, it's not at all obvious whether theory and experiment should exist side by side on one site or not (basically because experimenters and theorists basically neither understand nor are interested in each others jobs; on the other hand, both groups essentially share the same background and passion for physics). Personally, I think it would be best if there was a common research physics site. Anyway, that's something you might want to discuss under TP proposal, not here.

Comment: I hope it succeeds, but I think the low traffic of around 3 questions per day will kill it in the end.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's fantastic news. I'll try to promote the proposal more now that I know it's not about to be closed.

Comment: @LarryHarson: Your prophecy was right.