# Is there a place where can I read about the history and growth of physics stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, history

I'm just curious on how that community has grown over the years.

Comment: Reading a bunch of old meta threads will probably give you a good background.

Comment: @Mithrandir Haha, should I interpret that as a no, there's no concrete place where that information is all in one place and in order...(?)

Comment: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) is a public ms-sql mirror of the site (and also all other SE sites). With it, you can create various stats and reports for discussion. [New users pe rmonth](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1039977/new-users-month#graph), [upvotes/month](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1039973/yet-another-upvote-month-stat#graph), [questions/month](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1033605/yet-another-questions-per-month-stat#graph).

Comment: @peterh Pretty good, thanks.

Comment: @peterh that should be an answer...

Comment: @KyleKanos Op asked for texts, not for tables. Although I suspected, he will like also graphs.

Comment: @peterh there is nothing that says "texts" in the post. OP is looking for a source of information, SEDE queries can certainly provide that.

Comment: @KyleKanos OP wants to "read". Not to see graphs. At least, on the original text.

Comment: If you want an all-in-one-place history of physics in Stack Exchange, I suspect the closest you'll get is my answer to [How did mathematics end up with two Stack Exchange sites, while Physics only got one?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9822/how-did-mathematics-end-up-with-two-stack-exchange-sites-while-physics-only-got). More generally, it's pretty unclear to me exactly what type of answer you're looking for.